# I want to reverse the format of the output of the following code (both lines and line number should be in reverse order)

Tags: python

```
def ls():
    with open("todo.txt",'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
#       lines = reversed(lines)
        for num,line in enumerate(lines):
            print(num,line)
```

Output:

```
0 Lemon
    
1 StarFruit
    
2 Banana
    
3 Apple
    
4 Grapes
```

Expected Output:

```
5 Grapes
    
4 Apple
    
3 Banana
    
2 Starfruit
    
1 Lemon
```

Comment: Put back the call to `reversed`. That was correct. Then change the last line to actually print the number you want: `print(len(lines)-num,line)`.

Comment: It produce TypeError :. object of type `list_reverseiterrator` has no len()

Comment: Ah, sorry, a leftover Python 2 habit. Use `len(list(lines))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## use reversed() to read a file line by line backwards

```
textfile = open("todo.txt")
lines = textfile.readlines()
for line in reversed(lines):
    print(line)
```

Comment: I want the line number also ( descending order )